# Role of Cavity Resonators in continuous wavelength-electron paramagnetic resonance(CW-EPR)

Tags: condensed-matter, experimental-physics, spectroscopy, resonance, cavity-qed

Why is it necessary to place the sample in a cavity resonator for obtaining EPR spectrum in CW-EPR? What role does a cavity resonator play in a CW-EPR spectrometer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of a resonator in X-band EPR is required to overcome the intrinsically low signal over noise ratio, that is of the order of 1ppm. Using a resonator, the oscillating magnetic field is amplified and the electric component is cancelled, avoiding dielectric losses.

To take advantage of a resonator, it must be properly (critically) coupled to the microwave source so that most of the microwave energy remains trapped in the resonator.
That way, when the sample absorbs energy, the coupling is disrupted and microwave energy gets out of the resonator. This reflected component is what makes the EPR signal.

For EPR in the 100+ GHz domain, simple absorption designs can be used, so you don't need a resonator.